# bootstrap v3: layout issue with multiple buttons with glyphicon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

there is an layout issue on bootstap v3 on multiple buttons with glyphicon.

you can see the issue here : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22914

you can see snapshot of the issue with FF ESR 45.2.0 :
[image]

you can see snapshot of the issue with IE11 :
[image]

can you help me to solve this issue that boostrap's team won't to fix as they work only on v4?

Comment: Can you show your exact markup including buttons because I've tested this in both IE11 and FF without issue?  See [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xrPWXa).

Comment: I can see the issue on the bootstrap documentation page and with your example on codepen.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this in your header tag :

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: of course, my dev site use this bootstrap's hack
I fact, as described in the bootstrap issue, I can see the issue on boostrap 3 documentation pages, here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-multiple

so this not only a bug on my website, but iti is a boostrap issue!

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix to solve this issue. So I share it here.

The best way to fix the bootstrap issue is to set a height to the multiple buttons with glyphicon.
The height have to be setted to the height of the input form (34px by default).

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.input-group-btn-fix {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.btn-fix {
    height: 34px;
}
```

You can see it in action here: https://www.bootply.com/mtNO2DGZTW